# How to dynamically define secured URLs within an application in Spring Security 6.0.2

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

The official documentation is as follows:

```java
public class MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

    public List<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object) {
        FilterInvocation fi = (FilterInvocation) object;
            String url = fi.getRequestUrl();
            String httpMethod = fi.getRequest().getMethod();
            List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList<ConfigAttribute>();

            // Lookup your database (or other source) using this information and populate the
            // list of attributes

            return attributes;
    }

    public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAllConfigAttributes() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FilterInvocation.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }
}
```

I have written the code required for the commented section.

How to use MyFilterSecurityMetadataSource? I have no idea about it.

I have been looking for clues in the official documentation and samples, but found none.